# Scrapy Parsing Unwanted URLs

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm scraping apartments.com with Scrapy. I'm getting a few unwanted results. Specifically, I'm getting results from nearby cities and from the Spanish-language version of apartments.com. On the bottom of each apartment listing, there is a "nearby apartments" feature, which may be why Scrapy is getting results outside of Boston. I tried to prevent the /es/ listings with my deny rule but it doesn't appear to be working.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from apt.items import AptItem
from urllib.parse import urljoin
from scrapy.selector import Selector


class AptSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "apt"
    allowed_domains = ["apartments.com"]
    start_urls = ["https://www.apartments.com/boston-ma/"]

    rules = (Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=r'[1-9]+/*'), callback='parse_urls', follow=False),
    Rule(LinkExtractor(deny=(r'/es/.*', ))),)

    def parse_item(self, response):    
        //parse item code

    def parse_urls(self, response):
        apts = response.xpath("//*[contains(@class, 'property-link')]/@href").extract()
        for a in apts:
            url = urljoin(response.url, a)
            yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_item)
```

How can I exclude the Spanish results as well as the results outside of Boston?

Comment: I think they may be coming from your side only  `yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_item)`, if you do `es` link in this loop, they will be parsed as you asked for them

Answer (score 1):

The problem isn't Scrapy, it makes itself work very well. Your scraped site give not very correct results, but you can fix it. In a few minutes I found two ways to
solve problem:

## First way

Links of all appartaments in Boston have special format, like `https://www.apartments.com/<name>-boston-ma/<param>/`. Add this link format to your rule.

## Second way

Location addreses of all appartaments have special format too, like `<part_of_addres>, Boston, MA <code>`. You can check this parameter and if he is valid, then collect this info, otherwise skip.

**Update.** You can also try to find some search filters if they exist, and include them in your request to minimize number of requests count and take more correctly responses.

Comment: I recommend for you first way, but please make sure what I give correct link format because I found other links, like `https://www.apartments.com/<name>-boston-chelsea-ma/<param>/`. I don't know if you need such appartaments or no.